# How to constraint layout items by radius in Android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Can I define a radius relationship between two views in android XML?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ConstraintLayout - Add these attributes in your view B:

- `layout_constraintCircle` : set the id of view A.
- `layout_constraintCircleRadius` : Distance between the centers of these views.
- `layout_constraintCircleAngle` : Angle in degrees, defining the circular position of B in relation to A.